# ошибка 500 - получение запроса из mysql (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST,MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASS,MYSQL_DB);

$result = mysqli_query(SELECT * from `smf_members` WHERE member_name=certt);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo $row[`id_member`];

?>
```

Выдает

> HTTP ERROR 500

при таком вот php коде, подскажите что делать.

Если сделать записывать `mysqli_connect` в `&connect`, а потом делать проверку на `!mysqli_connect` - все коннектит, а как добавляю код самого получения - сразу проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используете процедурный стиль, то нужно писать так:

```
$con=mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST,MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASS,MYSQL_DB);
if(!$con) {
    exit(mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Не забываем про кодировку соединения (иначе возможен факт неправильной работы метода `mysqli_real_escape_string` и это можно будет обойти):

```
if (!mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8')) {
    exit("Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8: ".mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Не забываем про экранирование с помощью функции `mysqli_real_escape_string`

```
$str='certt'; // мало-ли откуда прилетело это значение.
$certt=mysqli_real_escape_string($str); // экранируем, если есть, что экранировать
$res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `smf_members` WHERE `member_name`='".$certt."'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo $row[`id_member`];
mysqli_close($con);
```

А вообще, рекомендую использовать объект класса `mysqli` и использовать `Подготавливаемые запросы`:

```
$str = 'certt';
$mysqli=new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST,MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASS,MYSQL_DB);
if($error = mysqli::$connect_error) {
    exit($error);
}
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    exit("Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8: " . $mysqli->error);
}
if($prepare = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `smf_members` WHERE `member_name`=?")) {
    $prepare->bind_param('s',$str);
    $prepare->execute();
    $res = $prepare->get_result();
    $res = $res->fetch_assoc();
    echo $res[`id_member`];
    $prepare->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```